# Multiplication map by a ring element on an object vs. all its suspensions in singularity category

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories, chain-complexes

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, consider the bounded derived category of finitely generated $R$-modules $D^b(R)$ and consider the singularity category $D_{sg}(R):=D^b(R)/D^{perf}(R)$. Let $r\in R$ and $X \in D_{sg}(R)$  be such that $X \xrightarrow{r} X$ is the zero map in $D_{sg}(R)$. My question is: Is it true that for every $n\in \mathbb Z$, the map $\Sigma^n X \xrightarrow{r} \Sigma^n X$ is also zero map?

Comment: Isn't $\Sigma$ a self-equivalence, in any triangulated category?

Comment: @DaveBenson: right, but is $\Sigma$ an $R$-linear functor?